# New custom menu created. how to apply it?

Tags: functions, menus, headers, theme-twenty-eleven

i have a childtheme from twentyeleven,

i created a 'inicio' (name) custom menu,

[image]

how can I apply it?

tried:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'inicio' ) ); ?>
```

but not working (not even change visible)

EDIT

Trying now:

header.php: (child)

---

```
<?php //wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'inicio' ) ); ?>
```

functions.php (child)

```
function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(array('inicio' => 'Inicio Menu'));
}
```

And still seeing 'default' navigation menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a theme locations dropdown titled inicio, select the menu you created here and it will work.

Alternately, if you just want to replace the main menu, select inicio in the Theme Locations box under Primary Menu.

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered 'inicio' as a new menu?

For example you'll need to add to theme's functions.php file

```
<?php
  add_theme_support( 'menus' );
  add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

  function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(array('inicio' => 'Inicio Menu'));
  }
?>
```

Informs WordPress that you're going to be using a Menu in this theme called 'inicio' and it should be shown in the administration backend as 'Inicio Menu'.

I'm not 100% sure of the child-parent theme relates in terms of adding a new menu, but hopefully this puts you in the right direction.

Once added to functions and your theme, your backend custom menus should give you Theme Locations - where you pick the custom menu name, and associate it to the location name on the theme (I've pretty much used the same names on my site, but hindsight I should have perhaps called the locations 'placeholder' or something similar).

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwypd.png for snapshot of how theme locations appear when they are registered. (Curses to less than 10 rep and no image posting)

Comment: tried that in a blank php file and still seeing the 'default' menu (home  ///  sample page). Any idea why?

Comment: Try de-selecting your current child-theme, save/reload and then reload the child theme again.

Comment: In your child's theme header.php file - Can you please add something random - just pure HTML like <p>Hey I'm here</p> - to see if you're getting to the right header.php file?
If you've made changes (and can see them) to header.php ignore this comment <_<

Comment: yes i made other changes in functions.php and header.php and they take effect... have you seen my edit? did i make the menu correctly?

Comment: hold up - i think i see the issue.

Comment: in functions.php - just remove what I've suggest you put in there, and put in
    <?php register_nav_menu( 'inicio', 'Inicio Menu' ); ?>
 - If you "added" the custom menu by hand in the backend, remove it - then deselect your theme, then re-add it in.  What's happening is wordpress is seeing your use of a new menu it still doesn't know how to associate with (I believe - I had a similar problem when I wasn't registering the menus properly)

Comment: On the left of your customer menu "(sorry you don't delete the customer menu you've made, you simply associate it with a location) - do you have "Theme Locations"?  That is where you associate your custom menu you made with the location name (inicio menu)

Comment: Yes... Please check if you're selecting the right theme location.

Comment: I am not sure if im following. So i only need to place your code in functions.php? Nothing in headers.php?? Thanks